# How to maintain state, when using add more button via AJAX?

Tags: forms

I have two dropdown list(question & answer). Onchange of "question" dropdown, "Answer" dropdown is populated, however when I click on "add more" button for adding fields using Ajax, the state of "Answer" dropdown is getting lost. Any help?

Please find the code snippet below.

```
function digitaliq_bckgrd_variable_add_more($form, &$form_state) {
  $options = array();
  $options['key1'] = t('value1');
  $options['key2'] = t('value2');
  $options['key3'] = t('value3');
  $options['key4'] = t('value4');

  // Because we have many fields with the same values, we have to set
  // #tree to be able to access them.
  $form['#tree'] = TRUE;
  $form['names_fieldset'] = array(
    '#type' => 'fieldset',
    '#title' => t('People coming to the picnic'),
    // Set up the wrapper so that AJAX will be able to replace the fieldset.
    '#prefix' => '<div id="frmbckgrdvariable">',
    '#suffix' => '</div>',
  );

  // Build the fieldset with the proper number of names. We'll use
  // $form_state['num_names'] to determine the number of textfields to build.
  if (empty($form_state['num_names'])) {
    $form_state['num_names'] = 1;
  }
  for ($i = 1; $i <= $form_state['num_names']; $i++) 
  {
    // First Field
    $form['names_fieldset']['question'.$i] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#title' => t('Question'),
    '#options' => $options,
    '#default_value' =>  0,
    '#ajax' => array(
       'callback' => 'digitaliq_bckgrd_variable_ajax_question_callback', $i,
       'wrapper' => 'answer-'.$i.'',
       'event' => 'change',
    ),
    );

    //Second Field
    $form['names_fieldset']['answer'.$i] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#disabled' => 0,
    '#prefix' => '<div id="answer-'.$i.'">',
    '#title' => t('Answers (select more by holding ctrl + click)'),
    '#options' => $options,
    '#default_value' =>  0,
    '#suffix' =>  '</div>',
    );
  }
  // Add More Button
  $form['names_fieldset']['add_name'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Add one more'),
    '#submit' => array('digitaliq_bckgrd_variable_add_more_add_one'),
    '#ajax' => array(
      'callback' => 'digitaliq_bckgrd_variable_add_more_callback',
      'wrapper' => 'frmbckgrdvariable',
    ),
  );

  if ($form_state['num_names'] > 1) {
    $form['names_fieldset']['remove_name'] = array(
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#value' => t('Remove one'),
      '#submit' => array('digitaliq_bckgrd_variable_add_more_remove_one'),
      '#ajax' => array(
        'callback' => 'digitaliq_bckgrd_variable_add_more_callback',
        'wrapper' => 'frmbckgrdvariable',
      ),
    );
  }
  // Form Submit
  $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Submit'),
  );

  return $form;
}
function digitaliq_bckgrd_variable_ajax_question_callback($form, &$form_state)
{
  $options = array();
  $options['some_value1'] = t('some_value1');
  $options['some_value2'] = t('some_value2');
  $options['some_value3'] = t('some_value3');
  $options['some_value4'] = t('some_value4');

  $form_state['complete form']['names_fieldset']['answer1']['#options'] = $options;
  $form['names_fieldset']['answer1']['#options'] = $options;
  $form_state['rebuild'] = false;
  return $form['names_fieldset']['answer1'];

}

/**
 * Callback for both ajax-enabled buttons.
 *
 * Selects and returns the fieldset with the names in it.
 */
function digitaliq_bckgrd_variable_add_more_callback($form, &$form_state) {
  return $form['names_fieldset'];
}

/**
 * Submit handler for the "add-one-more" button.
 *
 * Increments the max counter and causes a rebuild.
 */
function digitaliq_bckgrd_variable_add_more_add_one($form, &$form_state) {
  $form_state['num_names']++;
  $form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;
}

/**
 * Submit handler for the "remove one" button.
 *
 * Decrements the max counter and causes a form rebuild.
 */
function digitaliq_bckgrd_variable_add_more_remove_one($form, &$form_state) {
  if ($form_state['num_names'] > 1) {
    $form_state['num_names']--;
  }
  $form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;
}
```

Comment: what drupal version are you using?

Comment: Drupal 7 is the version i'm using